# Local Wordpress website (https) not loading from outside local network

Tags: wordpress, https

I just set up a wordpress website on my raspberry pi2. The website loads fine from the local network, but I wanted to make it accessible from the internet. To do this I first set up https using a self-signed ssl certificate.

I changed the wordpress address and site address in wordpress settings from http to https. Also modified the .htaccess file to redirect http to https (ref: [https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/#:~:text=First%2C%20you%20need%20to%20install,WordPress%20site%20to%20use%20HTTPs.](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/#:%7E:text=First%2C%20you%20need%20to%20install,WordPress%20site%20to%20use%20HTTPs.)).

So far so good; the site loads as https://myowndomain.com from the local network.

I then set up port forwarding on my wifi router to route external port 443 to local port 443. However, when I try to access the site over internet the site does not load at all.

Could someone please guide me on where I should start checking/looking for issues? I have no experience with apache2 or wordpress and followed instructions I found online to set this up.

1. I have an ssh port forwarding rule on the wifi router, so I know that the domain resolves to my public IP and I can ssh into the pi.
2. The website is a very simple one with no images (so far) and only contains some test posts. It is not meant to grow into a very active website; just for personal use.

Thanks and regards,

Aashish

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
From the browser console I saw that CSS could not be downloaded. Suspecting a path issue I updated the site URL and Wordpress URL in the general settings. I changed the URL from LAN IP address to the domain name. After this I was able to load the sire from outside my local network.